# vb.net Multithreading not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, delegates, invoke

I am learning how to do multithreading in vb.net. Here are the codes but it is not working.

the purpose of this program is to count the label1 and label2 from 0 to 100000 at the same time.

however, in the codes below, the label2 will only be counting up when label1 is finished. Can anyone teach me how to do it correctly?

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Thread1 As System.Threading.Thread

    Thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.Count1)
    Thread1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim Thread2 As System.Threading.Thread

    Thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.Count2)
    Thread2.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub InvokeIfRequired(del As [Delegate])

    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(del)
    Else
        del.DynamicInvoke()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub AddText1()

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until i = 100000
        i += 1
        Label1.Text = i
        Label1.Refresh()
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub AddText2()

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until i = 100000
        i += 1
        Label2.Text = i
        Label2.Refresh()
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Count1()

    InvokeIfRequired(Sub()
                         AddText1()
                     End Sub)

End Sub

Private Sub Count2()

    InvokeIfRequired(Sub()
                         AddText2()
                     End Sub)

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be testing to see whether an invoke is required when setting the Text of the label, not for the whole loop (and you don't need the refresh if it's in a separate thread)

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Count1()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until i = 100000
        i += 1    
        InvokeIfRequired(Sub() Label1.Text = i.ToString())
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now! but can i know why it can't used for the whole loop?

Comment: I think it is to do with the dynamic invoke. This is waiting to invoke the Text property for the duration of the loop, rather than each individual item

Comment: another problem occurred. When the two numbers are counting up, i can't do other things like closing the application or pressing other buttons(e,g, button 3). Why this happened and how can i solve it?

Comment: @IvanChan : This is because you keep the UI busy by updating it all the time in a very long loop. Every time you call `Invoke()` you queue some work to be done on the UI, and due to that your loop has no delay you'll make it busy immediately again. You could try invoking the individual control (each `Label`) instead of the entire form, however I'm not sure it would make much of a difference.

Comment: This is another kind of bug, a *firehose* bug.  The UI will be completely unresponsive, burning 100% core while the thread is running.  Trying to close it has no effect, after 5 seconds the "Not Responding" ghost window appears.  The only reason why it *seems* to work is because of the Refresh() call and 10000 probably not quite long enough to notice that the UI is dead.  This is not a good answer.